# Javascript appending class over existing class

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem implementing the Query Selector All method with classList. Basically, what I want to do is add the class `.purple` to all instances of the `fridge` class. However, it keeps telling me that it cannot add to undefined.

The code snippet below hopefully illustrates what I am trying to accomplish.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.fridge').classList.add('purple');
```

```css
.purple {color: purple;}
```

```html
<div class="fridge">Stuff</div>
<div class="fridge">Moar Stuff</div>
```

EDIT: I am looking for a plain JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) from `querySelectorAll` into an array and loop over it:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.fridge')).forEach(function (fridge) {
  fridge.classList.add('purple');
});
```

```css
.purple {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="fridge">Stuff</div>
<div class="fridge">Moar Stuff</div>
```

If you are able to use ES6, this can be shortened a bit:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.fridge')].forEach((fridge) => {
  fridge.classList.add('purple');
});
```

```css
.purple {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="fridge">Stuff</div>
<div class="fridge">Moar Stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is very easy-to-read code

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.fridge');
for (var x = items.length - 1; x >= 0; x--){
    items[x].classList.add('purple');
}
```

```css
.purple {color: purple;}
```

```html
<div class="fridge">Stuff</div>
<div class="fridge">Moar Stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Js, Try

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('fridge');
    for(i=0; i < a.length - 1; i++){
        a[i].classList.add('purple');
    };
```